# discordpy rewrite how to get the id of a slash command (Without hardcoding)

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am making a help command and would like the commands to be clickable. I looked at the [documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#message-formatting) and the format is </NAME:COMMAND_ID>.

The problem is I don't know how to get the command id. (I know i can copy it in discord itself but I don't want to hardcode every id) I also found nothing in the [Command documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=command#discord.app_commands.Command)

I already have this:

```
data = []
commands = cog.get_commands()
for command in commands:
    description = command.description.partition("\n")[0]
    data.append(f"</{command.name}:COMMAND_ID> - {description}")
```

Comment: PS: `cog.get_commands` doesn't return the slash commands, only normal commands. Use `cog.get_app_commands` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly there's only one way of getting the slash command ID

When syncing the commands, it returns a list of `AppCommand` objects, they have an ID attribute which corresponds to our Slash Command ID.
You can create a "cache" with the following code snippet:

```py
commands = await bot.tree.sync(guild=guild)

for cmd in commands:
    if cmd.guild_id is None:  # it's a global slash command
        bot.tree._global_commands[cmd.name].id = cmd.id
    else:  # it's a guild specific command
        bot.tree._guild_commands[cmd.guild_id][cmd.name].id = cmd.id
```

Then you can use it as so:

```py
# remember to firstly sync your commands otherwise this will be broken
commands = cog.get_app_commands()  # `get_app_commands()` not `get_commands()`

for command in commands:
    description = command.description.partition("\n")[0]
    data.append(f"</{command.name}:{command.id}> - {description}")
```